# Finding number that differs the most from a mean

Tags: function, excel-formula, mean

I'm trying to develop a spreadsheet that automates some calculations I'm having to do manually.

So I have 4 numbers that generate a mean and I then subtract the number that is further from the mean as a quality control step. If this QC is higher than 1 I have to then remove the number I used to calculate the QC and recalculate the mean with 3 numbers only.

My problem is how to write a formula that recalculates the mean by removing the number furthest from the original mean as I can't find a function to find this number.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: can you mock up a table that shows the data and expected output?  Then [edit] the post to include that mock up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I understood, although I guess you would not want so many helper cells.

[image]

- **Numbers** feature the input.
- **Consider flag** allows you to exclude (0) a given number from being used in the calculation of "Mean".
- **Distance** `=$C$11-C6` is the distance between the respective number and the mean.
- **Mean** `=SUMPRODUCT($C$6:C9,$D$6:$D$9)/COUNT($C$6:$C$9)`. I used SUMPRODUCT instead of AVERAGE as it allows me to include the "Consider flag".
- **Highest distance** `=MAX(ABS(MIN($E$6:$E$9)),ABS(MAX($E$6:E9)))` identifies the lowest and highest values in the "Distance" column and returns the highest absolute value of them.
- **Quality check** `=C11-$C$12` subtracts the "highest distance" from the "mean".
- **Action** `=IF(AND($C$13>1,ABS(E6)=$C$12),"out","-")` lets the user know, whether and which number has to be excluded by setting the respective "consider flag" to "0".

**Usage**

You enter your numbers and check whether the "action" column features a "out". Then you change the respective flag to zero.

Comment: Many thanks for this reply. I didn't exactly like that as I already had most of it done but the 'Flag' column helped solve it. I'll edit the question in a bit and add the adaptation of your solution I used.

Comment: Please note, that we can only work with what you tell us. And if you find some aspects of my or anyone else's answer useful, it would be kind to upvote it.